# Что означает *[int(i)?

Tags: python

Прохожу курс на степике и попалась одна задачка. После неудачных попыток полез в интернет и нашёл вот такое решение:

```
print(*[int(i)*'|' for i in input().split()], sep='\n')
```

Оно работает, но я не понимаю как. Конкретно не понимаю *[int(i), что означает в начале умножение списка? Мы говорим, что переменная i, это число, затем умножаем на строку | и в цикле число разбиваем на подстроки с помощью split.

Сама задача: Напишите программу, которая получает на вход список целых чисел, разделенных через пробел и на их основе строит линейные диаграммы.

Comment: Первая звёздочка - не умножение, а распаковка аргументов https://tproger.ru/translations/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/

Comment: Вторая звёздочка копирует строку указанное число раз, то есть например `3*'|'` даст `'|||'`

Comment: твой мозг мало кого интересует, а вот нормальная формулировка заголовка важна всем

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
print(*[int(i)*'|' for i in input().split()], sep='\n')
```

итак:

`input()` - получает ввод от пользователя (в виде строки)

`.split()` - разбивает строку на слова (через пробел или иной разделитель типа табуляции) и формирует их в список

`for i in input().split()` - пройти в цикле по всем словам из строки

`int(i)` - преобразовать слово в число (считаем что строка и есть число иначе будет ошибка)

`int(i)*'|'` - сформировать строку из символа `|` повторённого `i` раз

например `5 * 'a'` даст `'aaaaa'`

`[value for v in arr]` - формирует новый массив в который входит значение `value` вычисленное для каждого элемента `v` массива `arr`

т.е.

`[int(i)*'|' for i in input().split()]` - формирует список строк, содержащих `|`, повторённый `i` раз

`print(*arr)` - выводит на экран все элементы списка `arr` как отдельные элементы

`sep='\n'` - параметр функции `print` о том, что между двумя отображаемыми значениями надо поставить `\n` (т.е. каждое значение вывести с новой строки)

Таким образом алгоритм делает следующее:

- получает строку от пользователя
- разбивает ее на слова
- каждое слово переводит в число
- для каждого числа формирует строку из повторяющихся `|` (кол-во повторений * равно указанному числу)
- из полученных строк формирует список
- выводит каждый элемент списка на экран с новой строки

**P.S.**

тот же функционал, но другими способами:

**вариант 1 (код покороче, сразу формируем строку):**

```
print('\n'.join(int(i)*'|' for i in input().split()))
```

**вариант 2 (для любителей изврата):**

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\s*(\d+)\s*', lambda m: int(m[0])*"|"+'\n', input()))
```

Comment: Благодарю, что разложили по полкам и дали дополнительную информацию, теперь смог понять

Answer (score 2):

Логический эквивалент кода в вопросе

```py
input_ = input()

for i in input_.split():
    print(int(i) * '|')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за данный эквивалент

Comment: @Shishbamburish на здоровье)